# automatic request to web server for testing purpose

Tags: testing, server

I want to test my java web application for many user. for example- 2 or 3 thousand users request at the same time. It is in my local web server. Is there any specific software or popular technique, that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Use jmeter(http://jmeter.apache.org/) . It will let you to specifie number of user also the number of time you want to request. Besides any error during the testing. very useful program from testing web applications

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use **JMeter** or **loadrunner**. But Only JMeter is open source and best tool 
for load and performance testing.But make sure that your server quite enough 
to handle that much load. You can get all the basics regarding Jmeter over below **link**.
```

http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: "Best" is subjective.  There are many capabilities which JMETER lacks and which make it more of a load generation tool rather than a performance testing tool.  It has inherent weaknesses in monitoring of infrastructure and reporting of results.  But it can throw load.  The efficiency of test code creation, i.e. the time required to make a script, is also quite low with respect to any commercial tool.  In the end this means you will burn lots of labor hours to overcome the tool inefficiencies and tool inadequacies when compared to any commercial tool.  It's free like a puppy or old truck.